# Combining Variadic Template Concept

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++-concepts

I am trying to apply a concept defined on a single template class on multiple template classes and I do:

```
template<template<class> class F, class T, class... Ts>
    requires F<T>::value
struct check_concept
{
    constexpr bool value = check_concept<F, Ts...>::value;
};

template<template<class> class F, class T>
    requires F<T>::value
struct check_concept<F, T>
{
    constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

I get an error saying: `'check_concept<F,T,>::value' cannot be declared with 'constexpr' specifier`.

I would like to do something like:

```
template<class... Ts>
    requires check_concept<std::is_arithmetic, Ts...>::value;
class A
{
    //Implementation Details
}
```

I tried inheriting each time from `check_concept<template<class> class F, class... Ts>` but still fails.

Comment: What if you make both `bool`s `static`? They ought to be `static` anyway, right?

Comment: Thanks so much!!!! Works fine, Any reason why please?

Comment: Just a hunch :) It seemed pretty odd to have instance related variables in this context since they will be the same for all instances with the same template parameters.

Comment: Glad it helped! I would make a proper answer out of it, but I'm off to bed and someone else will most probably fill in the blanks with a proper answer soon.

Comment: DONE for you ;p

Comment: BTW, should it be `template<template<class> class F, class... Ts> struct check_concept
{ static constexpr bool value = (F<Ts>::value && ...); };`. Else the `requires` would avoid to have `check_concept<Ts...>::value` as `false`.

Comment: And fold expression might directly be used for `A`: requires((std::is_arithmetic_v<Ts> && ...))`

Comment: requires((std::is_arithmetic_v<Ts> && ...)) works just fine. I will go with that instead of reinventing the wheel, please feel free to put an answer for other people. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: you have "typo", missing `static`: i.e `static constexpr bool value =`.

Second: with your attempt, `check_concept<F, Ts...>::value` is always `true` or rejected.
You should instead do:

```
template<template<class> class F, class T, class... Ts>
struct check_concept
{
    static constexpr bool value = F<T>::value && check_concept<F, Ts...>::value;
};

template<template<class> class F, class T>
struct check_concept<F, T>
{
    static constexpr bool value = F<T>::value;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/azndE6zWo)

Third: no need of recursion for the definition, fold expression is enough:

```
template <template <class> class F, class... Ts>
struct check_concept
{
    static constexpr bool value = (F<Ts>::value && ...);
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r9Yhzns9e)

Finally, from the simple definition, that helper is not really needed, and `A` might directly be:

```
template<class... Ts>
    requires ((std::is_arithmetic<Ts>::value && ...));
// or requires std::disjunction_v<std::is_arithmetic<Ts>...>;
class A
{
    // Implementation Details
};
```